# Уверить в неотразимости без указания чьей - можно?

Tags: лексика

**Экспа́т** (англ. expat сокр. от expatriate, происходит от лат. ex patria «вне родины») — сленговое название для иностранных специалистов, реже самоназвание).

> А ещё в качестве развлечения мне нравится разглядывать в клубах или в
>   ресторанах старых экспатов, которых уверили в неотразимости
>   великодушные московские проститутки.

Если я влеплю "собственной", понятно ли будет, чья "собственная неотразимость"?

*...старых экспатов, которых уверили в собственной неотразимости великодушные московские проститутки.*

Если можно не править - не правим.

Если правим - как лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...старых экспатов, которых уверили в собственной неотразимости великодушные московские проститутки.

"собственная" относится к подлежащему "проститутки". Так еще хуже.

Не вижу ничего лучшего, чем исправить:

**старых экспатов, поверивших/уверовавших в собственную неотразимость благодаря великодушным московским проституткам.**

Comment: Спасибо! Беру "уверовавших" и "благодаря": *...старых экспатов, уверовавших в собственную неотразимость благодаря великодушию московских проституток* - вот так!